# Auto Login After Registration Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication, autologin

I would like that the user after clicking on the registration link sent via email (after the complete the registration form), log-in automatically without that he must enter your username and password.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is a security issue. You should verify the appropriate person received the email by asking for credentials. At most, you could probably store email in local storage/cookie and retrieve it on the login page. But please dont auto login.